# Understanding GDB syntax for C++ program

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

After performing the command `x/64ga $rsp`, I get this as one of the line output:

```
<Hex-addr-val> <Hex-addr-val> <Hex-addr-val> <Class_Name::Foo(Data_Type const&)+662>
```

So I understand everything on that line excepts for the '+662' part at the end. What does that number means in relation to the function? Is it a positive value at the time of crash? Or something else?

Comment: Offset from start of function? Purely a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does that number means in relation to the function?

It means that at location `$rsp+24` GDB found a value which *looks* like an address that points 662 bytes inside the code for `Class_Name::Foo()`.

It could be a coincidence, or it could be that that address was pushed onto the stack (e.g. because `Foo()` called some other function).

Using `x/i '&Class_Name::Foo(Data_Type const&)+662-5` may show that there is a `CALL` instruction at that address, which would be a strong indication that this is not just a random coincidence.